# One-to-One relation classes

Tags: python, oop

I want to have a class named `ProjectDirectory` and a class named `MetaDirectory`. Each project has a `MetaDirectory` which contains some meta data. Is it the good way to write the classes like this:

```
class ProjectDirectory(object):
    def __init__(self, directory=None):
        self.directory = directory
        self.meta_directory = MetaDirectory(self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.directory

class MetaDirectory(object):
    def __init__(self, project_directory=None):
        self.project_directory = project_directory
        self.directory = "%s/.meta/" % project_directory
```

`ProjectDirectory` has a reference to `MetaDirectory` and `MetaDirectory` has a reference to `ProjectDirectory`.

Is there an other solution or this solution is good ?

Comment: A minor point, consider changing `"%s/.meta/" % project_directory` to `os.path.join(project_directory, '.meta')`

Comment: It looks like you are storing each directory value twice. Why should the ProjectDirectory keep a meta_directory value, and vice-versa? And what do you gain by making them classes instead of just strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly fine, but since there is now a one to one connection between the classes, you could actually merge them. If you have many types of Directories beside ProjectDirectory, you could inherit from MetaDirectory instead.

But if for some reason you don't want to, the design above is fine. There isn't anything wrong with it per se.

Answer (score 0):

I would create Directory class and inherit those classes in your example from that class. If there more directory classes then inherit from Directory class too.

Answer (score 0):

Unless these directories **do** something special, ie perform extra actions based on whether a file is in a ProjectDirectory or MetaDirectory, I see no reason to make custom classes for them; I would suggest

```
import os

class BadDir(Exception): pass

class Dir(object):
    def __init__(self, dirName, test=True):
        self.dirName = os.path.abspath(dirName)
        self.isTested = test
        if test:
            self.test()

    def test(self):
        "Make sure the directory is valid"
        d = self.dirName
        if not os.path.exists(d):
            raise BadDir("The path '{0}' does not exist".format(d))
        if not os.path.isdir(d):
            raise BadDir("The path '{0}' is not a directory".format(d))

    def __add__(self, s):
        return Dir(os.path.join(self.dirName, s), self.isTested)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dirName

PROJECT = Dir('/Users/Me')
META    = PROJECT + 'Desktop'
FILE    = META + 'abc.txt'
```

results in

```
C:\Users\Me
C:\Users\Me\Desktop
BadDir: The path 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\abc.txt' is not a directory
```